# Calling a javascript function with evaluateJavaScript(..), to read a text file in the apps bundle

Tags: javascript, ios, xmlhttprequest, text-files, wkwebview

The first part works fine, this means the WKWebview object is able to call the java script function. The problem lies in the javascript code, I assume.

The javascript function, which is called, is supposed to read simply out of a text file in the app's bundle (fileName = "data.txt"). It looks like this:

```
function readTextFile(fileName)
{
     var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
     rawFile.onreadystatechange = function()
     { 
         if(rawFile.status == 4)
         { 
             document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
         }
     }

    rawFile.open("GET",file,true)
    rawFile.send()  

 }
```

The output is always empty. Now I am sure that rawFile status reaches 4, I checked that. I have replaced the fileName with some make-believe non existent file and the rawfile status still reaches 4. So now I am not even sure whether the file has been found.

1. Is there a way to determine whether the file was found?
2. If it is found how can I read out of it?

I am not an experienced java script developer at all. So it might be some obvious problem. The javascript function I wrote with help of w3schools.com.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some formatting issues with your code and you aren't adding an event listener. Try the below. Also there is better documentation at MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

```js
function readTextFile() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
}
function getTextFile(file) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.addEventListener("load", readTextFile)
  req.open("GET", file, true)
  req.send();
)

getTextFile('example.txt')
```

```html
<div id="demo">
</div>
```

Comment: Since the request is asynchron, it makes sense to add a listener, thanks I did not know how to implement this. It is not quite working yet, for the function readTextfile() is not called. There might be something else missing...

Comment: If the text file is placed in the apps bundle the function readTextFile is not called. Though if the text file is located on a remote webserver it is called. I eventually found out that the problem lies in that cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. This is apperently to due security restrictions... I will try to look for a work around...